# Failed import of gpg key, gpg: no writable keyring found: Not Found

Tags: linux, gpg

When I tried to import a gpg key in `exported_key` on a new computer with:

> user@computer:~$ gpg --import exported_key

It returned :

```
gpg: no writable keyring found: Not found                                                                                                                                                                   
gpg: error reading 'export': General error                                                                                                                                                                  
gpg: import from 'export' failed: General error                                                                                                                                                             
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually had for some reason root ownership of the files:

```
~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx~
```

Restoring the right ownership with:

```
chown user:user ~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx*
```

Fixed the issue :

> user@computer:~$ gpg --import exported_key

Returns nothing and :

> user@computer:~$ gpg --list-keys

Displays the new key.

Comment: I'm on OSX so I didn't change the owner group (it was the same for root), just added my username after chown, and this helped. Thanks!